# How can I remove the OPTIONAL value from a schema in Docusaurus using an OpenApi file?

Tags: json, openapi, docusaurus

I'm try to remove the OPTIONAL value from the schema in Docusaurus using an OpenApi file

This is the package.json that I use it.

```json
{
  "name": "my-websiteopenapi-2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@docusaurus/core": "^3.0.0",
    "@docusaurus/theme-classic": "^3.1.1",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^3.0.0",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "docusaurus-preset-openapi": "0.7.3",
    "prism-react-renderer": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "docusaurus": "docusaurus",
    "start": "docusaurus start",
    "build": "docusaurus build",
    "swizzle": "docusaurus swizzle",
    "deploy": "docusaurus deploy",
    "clear": "docusaurus clear",
    "serve": "docusaurus serve",
    "write-translations": "docusaurus write-translations",
    "write-heading-ids": "docusaurus write-heading-ids"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.5%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Remove the OPTIONAL from the Schema section,

[image]